# How to generate table using only unicode in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript in Thunder Head tool .

I am getting data some this like

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ Data1 + Data 2 + Data 3 + Data 4 +
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Now my ultimate aim is to generate table some thing like

```
___________________________________
| Data1 | Data2 | Data 3 | Data 4 |
-----------------------------------
```

We need to replace "~" with horizontal line and "+" with vertical line and I should get table look I tried with "|" and "-" but I am getting dotted lines and also the doesn't look like table and text is getting wrapped in borders if I try to change line space . There should not be any space. It should look like single like and form table look. I heard we can convent these symbols to Unicode's so they look exactly like table.

Comment: http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2500-257F

Comment: @ChrisG can you please tell me syntax how to use them

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5734311)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the link that was provided in the comment (http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2500-257F), you may want to use this method to achieve what you want:

- You can access the unicode characters using `\u`.

Here is a snippet:

```js
let cell_length = '\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500';
let output = '\u250c' + cell_length + '\u252c' + cell_length;

// etc, etc…

console.log(output);
```

Hope it helps.